# is it safe to make instagram API request from client side?

Tags: javascript, instagram, client-side, instagram-api

Based on [this](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) ,Instagram provide to access GET-based endpoints using JSONP which i know it include access token when making a request. We can load user photo just using client side using JSONP. I interest to using this method because it faster than load photos using server side.

Is it safe to include access token or URL that include access token in client side? if not, how to secure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything loaded to the client is unsecure and should not be count on to work properly. If someone experienced wants to get something from its content or change something on its way of working, he can no matter what you try. So in that regard no, it is not safe including access tokens.

It then boils down to: how much you care someone getting his hands on it?

They only possible answer to this, which will not work really, just make things harder to an 'attacker', is code obfuscation

Answer (score 1):

**No it is not secure.**

If you don't need to make too many requests, you should use your `CLIENT-ID` on the server-side, which gives you a limited quota ([5000 requests per hour per application](https://instagram.com/developer/limits/)).

You should use your `ACCESS-TOKEN` on the server-side, and not on the client-side because anyone can see it. This will allow you to have a higher quota. (5000 requests per hour per token)